# Nuxt Vuex mutation runs but doesn't update state

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I'm trying to get some data by nuxtServerInit and save it in state

store/index.js

```
import { fireDb } from '~/plugins/firebase'

export const state = () => ({
  posts: []
})

export const mutations = {
  addPosts (state, post) {
    state.posts.push(post)
    console.log('mutation =>', state.posts.length)
  }
}

export const actions = {
  nuxtServerInit (state, ctx) {
    fireDb.collection('posts').orderBy('timestamp', 'desc').limit(3).get().then((snapshot) => {
      snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        state.commit('addPosts', doc.data())
      })
      console.log('action => ', state.posts.length)
    })
  }
}
```

when I run this code console output is

```
mutation => 1                                                                                                                      
mutation => 2                                                                                                                      
mutation => 3                                                                                                                      

ERROR  Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

And vue dev tools also doesn't show there's data inside posts[].
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `nuxtServerInit` is dispatched as an action with the Nuxt [context](https://nuxtjs.org/api/context). Being an action, the first argument will be the Vuex [context](https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#actions).

The Vuex context exposes several properties including `state` and `commit`.

The [docs](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store/#the-nuxtserverinit-action) also say:

> Note: Asynchronous `nuxtServerInit` actions must return a Promise or leverage async/await to allow the `nuxt` server to wait on them.

You can change your code to:

```
async nuxtServerInit({state, commit}, ctx) {
    let snapshot = await fireDb.collection('posts').orderBy('timestamp', 'desc').limit(3).get();
    snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        commit('addPosts', doc.data())
    });
    console.log('action => ', state.posts.length)
}
```

Comment: Thanks it solved the " 'length' of undefined" error but still dev tools shows nothing has updated

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you mean with that? Because this function runs server-side it might not look the same as when you update Vuex state client-side.

Comment: it's looks like this https://imgur.com/a/ITHUxax . Code says state has been updated but dev tools doesnt show any update

Comment: Just saw this sentence in the docs: "Note: Asynchronous nuxtServerInit actions must return a Promise or leverage async/await to allow the nuxt server to wait on them." Will update my answer to use async/await. Sounds like the server is responding before having fetched the data.